почему ничего не выводится в консоль
написал скрипт, но в консоль нечего не выводит сам скрипт:
public class one : MonoBehaviour

    public int num1 = 52;
    public int num2 = 69;

    void Start()
    {
        int sum = num1 + num2 ;
        
        Debug.Log (message: "Sum_" + sum);


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Почему ты думаешь, что что-то должно выводиться в консоль?

А этот объект активирован?

Если вы делаете этот проект для работы с консолью, то попробуйте это -
using System;
class test{
    int main()
    {
        int num1 = 52;
        int num2 = 69;
        int sum = num1 + num2;
        console.Write("Sum_" + sum);
    }
}


Зачем такие сложности?  Console.Write("Hello World"); было бы достаточно.
